# Populating missing data using one of the concatenated datasets

Tags: sas

So I have imported several csv files of biomarker data and merged into a dataset called bioma. I have set bioma into a lab dataset as it needs to be integrated for a lab transfer. My question is how can I use the date of birth (LB_BDT_C) present in the original lab data to populate each subjects birth date in the csv files when concatenating/merging?. I know there is a coalesce function in a proc sql join that maybe would achieve this but I'm sure there is a more efficient way when merging/concatenating the data. The birth date is not present in the bioma dataset/excel files. Apologies if I'm being simple and missing a basic trick here cause it definitely feels like I am

[image]

Comment: Show your code, the `IMPORT` , `MERGE`, and `SET`.  Depending on the imports you might have to stack all the data, then sort nodupkey-wise into a LOOKUP table by ID and where not missing DOB.  A subsequent pass can MERGE the stack with the LOOKUP and populate the missing DOB with the lookup DOB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this after some help and it seems to have done the trick

```
proc sql;
    create table distinctDOB as
        select distinct CLIENTID
                        ,LB_BDT_C
        from LAB2
        where LB_BDT_C is not null
    order by 1;
quit;
proc sort data=LAB2; by CLIENTID;
data LAB;
    merge LAB2 (drop=LB_BDT_C)
          distinctDOB;
    by CLIENTID;
    RUN;
```